# Bind tcp socket to specific src port before connecting to remote server without SSL in PHP

Tags: php, sockets

Im trying to open a client side PHP socket and bind the socket to a specific source port before making the connection..

For example my Current code is:

```
$destination_ip = 1.2.3.4;
$destination_port = 6060;
$local_source_port = 35587;  <-- This is important

$sock= socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_connect($sock , $destination_ip , $destination_port);
```

However i cant find a way to specify the source port to use before opening the connection therefore the source port changes all the time, im aware you can use bindto but only with ***stream_socket_client*** however when i use that on this specific remote tcp server it appears to not connect properly, maybe because the destination is using TLS and not SSL?

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Just use [socket_bind](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php). Duplicate of [How to specify the port that the client side of socket in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479452/how-to-specify-the-port-that-the-client-side-of-socket-in-php). This has nothing to do with TLS  enabled or not. *"... it appears to not connect properly..."* - this is not a usable error description.

Comment: Hi Steffen, i had already read that thread and tried it but i couldn't get socket_bind to work, Could you please provide a basic example of using socket bind similar to my example above as im pretty sure i was doing it correct. Thanks

Comment: Hi Steffen, its resolved now, the issue was binding to the local ip, i had to use the public ip not 127.0.0.1 due to the interface